# Android-Kotlin : BitmapFactory gives nullpointer exception

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmapfactory

this is my code

```
 private fun initDesign(imageList: List<ImageList>) {
        //Initialize with empty data

        for (i in 0 until imageList.size) {

            val imageDataBytes = imageList.get(i).image
            val iD = Integer.parseInt(imageList.get(i).imageIndex)
            val  imageAsBytes : ByteArray  = Base64.decode(imageDataBytes,0)
            bitmaps !!.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.size))
            imageID!!.add(iD)
        }
}
```

what was the wrong with this code

Comment: @skIndia please update question with what you are passing in "imageList".

Comment: @YvetteColomb my problem is why it is getting an exception while decoding byte array

Comment: @ankitpatidar Imagelist.image is an String

Comment: ok let me check once thanks

Comment: @ankitpatidar  bitmaps !!.add(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.size)) at this line I am getting error

Comment: please do check, you initialised the "bitmaps" arraylist?

Comment: @ankitpatidar yes its ArrayList   val bitmaps: ArrayList<Bitmap>? = null

Comment: okay wait for some time

Comment: @skIndia as it stands the question is impossible to answer, as you haven't provided us enough detail. You need to post your stack trace/log cat. By the time you do that it will be closed as a duplicate. The community has voted that nullpointerexceptions can be solved by following the answers in the question I've marked for you. Please go through and read the answers carefully.

Comment: ohho bro, write it as :: val bitmpas: ArrayList<Bitmap> = ArrayList()

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: @ankitpatidar Thanks, bro it works its stupid mistake thanks a lot.